# BytesIO -> BufferedIOBase -> TextIOWrapper not possible to readlines

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

I am trying to read lines from bytes like object.

Here is a very simple example. I know it can be done in a different way but it's important to keep that flow (`BytesIO -> BufferedIOBase -> TextIOWrapper`).

```
import io
bytes_io = io.BytesIO(b"a\nb\nc")
buffered_io_base = io.BufferedIOBase(bytes_io)
text_io = io.TextIOWrapper(buffered_io_base)
for line in text_io:
    print(line)
```

This end up with an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

Python version 3.6.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`io.BufferedIOBase` *should not be instantiated*, it isn't even supposed to have a public constructor. You certainly don't need it here, it is a *base class* there to document the methods that buffered I/O objects must implement, with default implementations that inheriting classes can build upon.

From the [`io.BufferedIOBase` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase):

> Base class for binary streams that support some kind of buffering. It inherits `IOBase`. There is no public constructor.

You only need to use `BytesIO`, it *inherits* from `BufferedIOBase`, it is itself already implementing the methods required to be a buffered I/O object. From the [`io.BytesIO` documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO):

> It inherits `BufferedIOBase`. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> `BytesIO` provides or overrides these methods in addition to those from `BufferedIOBase` and `IOBase`: [...]

Wrap your `BytesIO` object directly in a `TextIOWrapper()` object here:

```
>>> import io
>>> bytes_io = io.BytesIO(b"a\nb\nc")
>>> text_io = io.TextIOWrapper(bytes_io)
>>> for line in text_io:
...     print(line, end='')
...
a
b
c
```

Where the `TextIOWrapper` documentation tells you that the first argument is expected to be a `BufferedIOBase` binary stream, the goal is to tell you you need a subclass of `BufferedIOBase`, something that *implements* that interface. `BytesIO` is such an object, and so are [`io.BufferedIOReader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedReader), [`io.BufferedIOWriter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedWriter), [`io.BufferedRandom()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedRandom), and [`io.BufferedRWPair()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedRWPair).

In general, you wouldn't create instances of any of the [ABCs listed in the *Class Hierarchy* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#class-hierarchy) of the documentation. They are there to provide documentation, something to test for when you need to check types, and to be a solid base from which to derive custom implementations.